Control multiple LM2596 with just one potentiometer
I have 20 of the cheap buck convertors (LM2596), On my boards there's this blue potentiometer on it which adjusts the output voltage very conviniently.
I wanted to use 20 of these buck convertors in my project for 20 different servos individually.
Can I use just one potentiometer connected to all 20 LM2596 boards simultaneouly to keep the output voltage exactly the same across all of them?
If so, does someone know exactly which one? or can I just use the same blue on it and connect all the lm2596 boards together (get rid of the rest 19 of them)?


There is no link to a datasheet or schematic of the LM2596 based buck-convertor in the question.
The onsemi LM2596 datasheet shows the following test circuit:

Which shows the resistors (R1 and R2) which set the output voltage are in the feedback path for the regulator. Therefore, it is not possible to use a single potentiometer to adjust the output voltage of multiple regulators.
For the buck-convertor in the question I'm guessing the potentiometer is in place of R2 in the above diagram from the datasheet.
While it's not directly related to the question, depending upon the source of the cheap buck convertors be aware that you may have Counterfeit LM2596 Regulator Boards .

Hello, Thanks for the answer, yeah I am sorry for no datasheet, I am certain its not genuine and I just read the article, I saw that these onsemi lm2596 are really cheap to buy from good vendors, can I just replace all those lm2596 and still keep the boards or the fake ones just all overall trash components?

@RolandThsive Counterfeit lm2596 works at 50 kHz (instead of 150) and so its output is more noisy. But, probably, this will not create any problems in your case. Also, the board is not suitable for high current. But if you're below one amp per each converter then there shouldn't be any issues, I guess.

@RolandThsive The answer, which also notes "cheap "LM2596" modules" are usually fake and counterfeit contains Eventually the low quality, high-ESR output cap will die and output voltage ripple will go out of control, but that shouldn't happen when it's new. I.e. probably not worth just replacing the LM2596 if the other components may be low quality.

@ChesterGillon thanks. i looked into it deeply, Ended up creating a custom power regulating board by myself with onsemi AP63357. Its better and faster switching. Good stuff. Yeah i will be using these regulators at 1.4A max continuous under full load.

Each regulator requires feedback from its own output. You can't control 20 adjustable regulators by connecting them to single potentiometer.
If you want to fix the voltage, replace the pot with fixed resistors.
However, due to manufacturing tolerances of both the resistors and the regulators, different loads on them, and each switching asynchronously with each other, so you can't have exactly the same voltage on the outputs.
However, you can have all of them in some nominal voltage which is  between some margin of tolerance.

Thankyou for your answer. I wanted to turn these 20 regulator board to have an output of 5V - 7V (adjustable on the go) without too much hassle for example turning all 20 individually, Do you have any suggestion regarding this problem.

@RolandThsive "If you want to fix the voltage, replace the pot with fixed resistors."

yeah but that fixes the voltage, doesnt let me hover it between 5V - 7V. However, I just gave up on it. Thanks. I will turn those pots i guess.
